# How do you show this "easy" ultrafilter property

Tags: elementary-set-theory, filters

How do you show this property of ultrafilters?

> If $\mathcal{F}$ is a filter on $A$, then $\mathcal{F}$ is an ultrafilter iff for all $X,Y \subseteq A$: if $X\cup Y \in \mathcal{F}$ then either $X\in \mathcal{F}$ or $Y\in \mathcal{F}.$

From the definition, $\mathcal{F}$ is an ultrafilter of $A$ if it is a maximal filter. In other words $\mathcal{F}$ is an ultrafilter if it is a filter of $A$, and if we add any collection of subsets of $A$ to $\mathcal{F}$ it is no longer a filter.  That is, if we expand $\mathcal{F}$ to $\mathcal{F}'$, then for any two $X,Y\in \mathcal{F}'$ where at least one of them not in $\mathcal{F}$, one of the conditions of a filter must be violated.  How do we go from here to the given lemma?

Comment: Suppose neither $X$ nor $Y$ is in $\mathcal F$, then $A\setminus X\in\mathcal F$ and $A\setminus Y\in\mathcal F$, hence also $(A\setminus X)\cap (A\setminus Y)\in \mathcal F$, but the latter set is the complement of $X\cup Y$, so you have both this set and its complement in $\mathcal F$, a contradiction.

Comment: @AlessandroCodenotti where does this use the fact that $\mathcal{F}$ is an ultrafilter? Is $X\notin \mathcal{F}$ implies $A\backslash X \in \mathcal{F}$ a property of only ultrafilters?

Comment: @AlessandroCodenotti Wouldn't this prove that every filter is an ultrafilter?  Unless I'm mistaken, your proof uses only the fact that $\mathcal{F}$ is a filter.  Then $\mathcal{F}$ is a filter implies that $X\cup Y\in \mathcal{F} \rightarrow X\in \mathcal{F} \vee Y\in \mathcal{F}$.  But then by the lemma above, $\mathcal{F}$ must be an ultrafilter.  There must be an error in either your proof or my reasoning.  But I can't find it.  I think your proof is valid which is why I'm so confused because it seems like there shouldn't be a contradiction in it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, $\forall X \subseteq A (X \notin \mathcal F \!\implies\! A \setminus X \in \mathcal F)$ is a property only for ultrafilters:

> Suppose that there exists a subset $X$
> of $A$ such that $X \notin \mathcal F$ and $A \setminus X \notin \mathcal F$. Then $\mathcal F \cup \{X\}$ has the finite intersection property: if $S_1,\dots,S_n \in \mathcal F$ then $(S_1 \cap \cdots \cap S_n) \cap X \neq \varnothing$ (otherwise $S_1 \cap \cdots \cap S_n \subseteq A \setminus X$ and then $A \setminus X \in \mathcal F$ since $S_1 \cap \cdots \cap S_n \in \mathcal F$). Thus there exists a filter $\mathcal F'$ that contains $\mathcal F \cup \{X\}$, but that means $\mathcal F$ cannot be maximal.

Comment: That makes sense, my reasoning for why its true for all filters is that if $X\notin \mathcal{F}$ and $X\backslash A\notin \mathcal{F}$ then they must both be in the dual ideal.  But then their union is in the dual ideal, i.e. $A\in \mathcal{I}$. Why is this not right?

Comment: I mean $A\backslash X$ not $X\backslash A$ in the comment above.

Comment: What is the dual ideal? You mean $\mathcal I = \{A \setminus F : F \in \mathcal F\}$?

Comment: yes thats the definition my text gave

Comment: How $X \in \mathcal I$? If $X \in \mathcal I$, then $X = A \setminus F$  for some $F \in \mathcal F$, so $A \setminus X = F \in \mathcal F$.

Comment: right. For every set in the filter, its complement is in its dual ideal.  And visa versa. though I might be missing something

Comment: Then your argument, namely $X \notin \mathcal F \ \& \ A \setminus X \notin \mathcal F \implies X \in \mathcal I \ \& \ A \setminus X \in \mathcal I \implies A \in \mathcal I$, is wrong. I think that answers why we need for $\mathcal F$ to be an ultrafilter.

Comment: Yeh i think thats it.   it is a property of filters that $X\in \mathcal{F} \rightarrow A\backslash X\notin \mathcal{F}$.  But it is a property of only ultrafilters that $X\notin \mathcal{F} \rightarrow A\backslash X\in \mathcal{F}$.  Thats it.  thanks for your trouble!